# Why is HttpClient.PostAsJson sending a Get Request

Tags: c#, post, get, asp.net-core-webapi

When the line below

```
        HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(resource, request);
```

is called, **the HttpClient is sending a GET request** (confirmed with fiddler) to the endpoint even though the method called is PostAsJsonAsync. It does the same if I call PostAsync or PostAsJson.

This causes a failure, because the WebApi endpoint I am calling only accepts posts and not gets. **Does anyone have any idea why this would be happening?**

Class I am using below:

```
public class LaneRestClient : IDisposable
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public LaneRestClient(IOptions<LaneApiConfigurationOptions> laneApiOptions)
    {
        var laneApiConfigurationOptions = laneApiOptions.Value;
        _httpClient = new HttpClient();
        _httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(laneApiConfigurationOptions.LaneApiUrl);
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        var byteArray = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes($"{laneApiConfigurationOptions.LaneApiUsername}:{laneApiConfigurationOptions.LaneApiPassword}");
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("gzip"));
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("deflate"));

    }

    public async Task<TResultType> Post<TResultType, TRequestType>(string resource, TRequestType request)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(resource, request);

        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            throw new HttpRequestException("Lane Api Request Failed: " + response.StatusCode + " - " +
                                           response.ReasonPhrase);
        }

        string resultJsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResultType>(resultJsonString);
        return result;

    }

}
```

This is using a .NET Standard API client library being called by a .NET Core 2.0 web application and making a call to a .NET Framework WebAPI2, if that is relevant.

Comment: Is the endpoind responding initially with a 30x redirect?

Comment: No, the initial request goes out as a GET request and the server responds with a 405 'Method not supported'. The 405 makes sense because the end point only accepts Post requests.

Comment: Well you know I frankly find that quite impossible to believe. If HttpClient in Core were broken and wouldn't POST anymore, you wouldn't be the first to notice. Try creating a [mcve] without all the boilerplate and wrapper code you have here.

Comment: @CodeCaster I agree. I think I am not configuring the HttpClient properly, but it also may be because of something unusual and unrelated. I am asking here because HttpClient is a popular and important class and I suspect it might be an unrelated issue with my local environment...like maybe a common proxy server setting or something else I haven't thought of.

Comment: @CodeCaster funny thing about Fiddler filters...

Looks like I got a 302 redirect when I tried it again after considering your comment some more and resetting Fiddler.

Comment: @CodeCaster if you want to post an answer that says "When using IIS redirects from HTTP to HTTPS a client that is redirected from a POST will then make a GET request even though the endpoint doesn't support it" I'll mark it as an answer. Telling me to recheck the obvious had me find the answer.

Comment: Hope you'll agree with a duplicate vote as well. The fact that there was a redirect was a guess, and not apparent from your question, so unfair as an answer. :)